# Having issues with css and maybe html of a single page on my site

Tags: html, css

I'm a web design student and still haven't gotten the hang of everything yet. I've been playing with this for awhile and I'm trying to make it work but one specific page on my website isn't working. Can't seem to figure out why, hence why I said "maybe" html, since im not completely sure that it's a css issue.

Here is my site and the specific page I'm having issue with: http://phlbombers.com/teamlist.html

**First problem** is I want the "This Season" section to be up much farther. If you click any of the other tabs, you will see that that section is in the same spot in all other pages, and you can see it just as soon as you click on the page. Sadly that is not the case on the "team" page.

**Second problem** is with the pictures. I want the first two pics to be stacked, exactly like they are. Problem occur's when I get to pictures three through six. I want those four pictures to be stacked 2 x 2. Is it possible to do that with a class setup, or would I need to change to a ID selector?

**HTML**

```
<div id="col3">
<h2>End of 2014/2015 Season playoff's pic</h2>
<div class="img">
  <a target="_blank" href="images/IMG957247.jpg">
    <img src="images/IMG957247.jpg" alt="2014/2015 Season" width="450" height="300">
  </a>
  <div class="desc">2014/2015 Season</div>
</div>
<h2>Bomber's 2014/2015 Admiral game outing</h2>
<div class="img">
  <a target="_blank" href="images/IMG_0400.jpg">
    <img src="images/IMG_0400.jpg" alt="Bomber's Admiral game outing" width="450" height="300">
  </a>
  <div class="desc">Bomber's Admiral game outing</div>
</div>
<h2>2015 Bomber's golf outing pictures</h2>
<div class="img">
  <a target="_blank" href="images/golf.jpg">
    <img src="images/golf.jpg" alt="Winners of the 2015 gold outing" width="450" height="300">
  </a>
  <div class="desc">Winners of the 2015 gold outing</div>
</div>
<div class="img">
  <a target="_blank" href="images/golf2.jpg">
    <img src="images/golf2.jpg" alt="2015 golf outing" width="450" height="300">
  </a>
  <div class="desc">2015 golf outing</div>
</div>
<div class="img">
  <a target="_blank" href="images/golf3.jpg">
    <img src="images/golf3.jpg" alt="2015 golf outing" width="450" height="300">
  </a>
  <div class="desc">2015 golf outing</div>
</div>
<div class="img">
  <a target="_blank" href="images/golf4.jpg">
    <img src="images/golf4.jpg" alt="2015 golf outing" width="450" height="300">
  </a>
  <div class="desc">2015 golf outing</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**with CSS:**

```
div.img { border: 1px solid #ccc; float: left; width: 300px; clear: both; margin-bottom: 10px; }

div.img:hover { border: 1px solid #777; }

div.img img { width: 100%; height: auto; }

div.desc { padding: 15px; text-align: center; }
col3 h2 {

padding-bottom: 10px;
font-size: 2em;
border-top: 1px solid;
border-left: 5px solid;
padding-top: 10px;
padding-left: 5px;
Float: left;
border-color: #A28B84;
color: #C2443D;
margin-bottom: 20px;
clear: both;

}
```

I'm sure im leaving some info that is needed out, which is why I linked the page itself. If need be, you can always inspect it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First problem**

You're missing the following in your css:

```
.col3{
    float: left;
    width: 600px;
}
```

Without these, your `.col3` would just take up the entire page width, and your Season box would place itself below it.

**Second problem**

Create a containing div around each post/gallery item, so your structure looks like this:

```
<div class="post">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <div class="img">...</img>
    <div class="img">...</img>
</div>
```

This will give the `img` divs a place to float in. Now just remove the `clear: both` from your `.img` class since this negates your `float` property.

Also remember to change the `width` of your `.img` to `298px`, because right now the div is `302px` wide in total (300px width + 2px border) and will not fit 2x2.

---

I suggest reading up on [how floats work](https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/) to better grasp the concept and how to use them correctly.

Comment: HUGE help, thank you. I saw your initial help for problem #1 and it was a definitely a slap on the forehead "duh" moment. So thank you for that. 

Going to work on the second part now. Appreciate it!